# is there a way to remove title on each screens in expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

i am a beginner  in react-native, i follow tutorials on youtube to make projects. i am trying to make an expo ui-app, but each screens has a title on the top like this:
[image]

There is the word Explore above the screen, and each other screens has the corresponding title above it aswell. Is there a way to remove this? because i followed tutorials from youtube but they didnt have this title.

Here is the Explore.js file:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, TextInput, Platform, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


class Explore extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.startHeaderHeight = 80
    if(Platform.OS == 'android')
    {
      this.startHeaderHeight = 100 + StatusBar.currentHeight
    }
  }

  render() {
   return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ height: this.startHeaderHeight, backgroundColor: 'white', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: '#dddddd' }}>
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', padding: 10, backgroundColor: 'white', marginHorizontal: 20, shadowOffset:{width:0,height:0}, shadowColor: 'black', shadowOpacity: 0.2, elevation: 1, marginTop: Platform.OS == 'android' ? 30 : 20 }}>
            <Ionicons name="ios-search" size={20} color="black" />
            <TextInput 
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              placeholder='Try Indonesia'
              placeholderTextColor="grey"
              style={{ flex: 1, fontWeight: '700', backgroundColor: 'white', marginLeft: 10 }}            
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
export default Explore;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
```

and here is my app.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { FontAwesome5 } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 


import Explore from './screens/Explore';
import Saved from './screens/Saved';
import Trips from './screens/Trips';
import Inbox from './screens/Inbox';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function BottomTabs() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>

      <..... CODE OF THE BOTTOM TAB NAVIGATOR IN HERE .....>

    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could hide the header using the `options={{headerShown: false}}` prop as follows.

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function BottomTabs() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Test" options={{
            headerShown: false 
          }}/>
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

David Scholz's solution is good for individual screens. If you want to disable the header on all child screens of a navigator, you can use

```
  screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
```

as a prop on the `Tab.Navigator`, or any top-level navigator.